# DotNetZip extract prevents process from accessing file

Tags: c#, .net, file, .net-4.0, dotnetzip

I'm using the [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library to extract files from a zip file.

```
using(ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipLocation))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip){
        entry.Extract(_updateDir);
        Log.Write("Unpacked: " + entry.FileName, Log.LogType.Info);
    }

    zip.Dispose();
}
```

Later on, I attempt to edit one of the files that I extracted.

```
var updateList = allFiles.Where(x => x.Contains(".UPD"));
foreach (string upd in updateList){
    string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(upd);
    int index = Array.IndexOf(result, "[Info]");

    //then I do stuff with index
}
```

At the line

```
string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(upd);
```

I get the exception: `The process cannot access the file <file name> because it is being used by another process.`

I know that this exception is being thrown because the file is in use elsewhere. The only place it is in use before `File.ReadAllLines(upd)` is in the DotNetZip code above.

Is there a way in the DotNetZip code to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem it's not from DotNetZip. I tried the code in my project and it works file:

```
[Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read("D:/ArchiveTest.zip"))
            {
                foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip)
                {
                    entry.Extract("D:/ArchiveTest");
                }

                zip.Dispose();
            }

            var updateList = Directory.GetFiles("D:/ArchiveTest").Where(x => x.Contains(".UPD"));
            foreach (string upd in updateList)
            {
                string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(upd);
                int index = Array.IndexOf(result, "[Info]");

                //then I do stuff with index
            }
        }
```

Probably another process is using the file you are trying to read. If you have Windows7 or Windows8, you can use the built-in Resource Monitor. Read this post: [How to know what process is using a given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565218/how-to-know-what-process-is-using-a-given-file)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that tool was useful. Another process somewhere else was aslo using the same file.